# removing unwanted jars pom.xml automatically downloads

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In my pom.xml ,even though i have not declared a dependency for commons logging and slf4j i can see them being automatically getting downloaded by maven.Is there a way to specify globally in pom.xml for the exclusion of these jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your included a `dependency` in your `pom.xml` which is dependent on `commons logging` and `sl4j`. This is [transitive dependency](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) mechanism used by maven.

Go to `Dependency Heirarchy` Tab in `eclipse` to find out which dependency is downloading the logging dependencies.

Then you need use the `<exclusions>{dependency}</exclusions>` to exclude the dependency.
This [maven page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) has good information on how to exclude transitive dependencies.